# Javascript syntax to add a loop variable inside another variable

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, text

I am looking to incorporate the following id variables: e1, e2, etc. into a loop.

What is the right syntax to handle the **'#e'+i** and **'#e'+i** elements, to avoid writing multiple functions eg. : `$(document).on('change', '#e1', function() {` and `var exp = 'e1';` 

PS: Currently, the below ***on change*** function is not triggered.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {      
        
$(document).ready(function() {          
              $(document).on('change', '#e'+i, function() {
                if ($("#e"+i).is(":checked")) {     var chk = $('#e'+i).val(); var exp = 'e'+i; }
                else {  chk = 0 ;   var exp = 'e'+i;    }
                $.ajax({
                        url: "modify.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {check: chk, experience: exp },
                  });
              });       
            })
            ;
        }
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic IDs (ever, not just to solve this issue). Use common classes instead, so you can then delegate the event to all elements matching a particular class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making your life more difficult and your code too complicated. Consider this approach, which uses a class name rather than dynamic id's.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('change', '.changeable', function() {
    let data = {
      check: $(this).is(":checked") ? $(this).val() : 0,
      experience: $(this).data('ref')
    }
    return console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
      url: "modify.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: data,
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' data-ref="e1" class="changeable" value='val1' />
<input type='checkbox' data-ref="e2" class="changeable" value='val2' />
<input type='checkbox' data-ref="e3" class="changeable" value='val3' />
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you! Kinglish and @CertainPerformance